# javascript regex decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var re = /^([0-9]*)(\.[0-9]{2})$/

re.test(.22)
true
re.test(.20)
false
re.test(10.02)
true
re.test(10.00)
false
```

I want it to pass for 10.00, 10.02, 10.20. Looks like its only passing for 10.02.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because numbers do not have significant digits and it drops the zeros. `re.test(10.00)` is actually `re.test(10)`

Comment: what is the solution? I have an array of single string  arr= ['0.001.000.90'] I want to split it like [0.00,1.00,0.90] for which I need the regex.

Comment: `re.test("10.00")` should work fine

Comment: And a string that has a number in it is different than a number. What is the exact problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: If you are just curious about why it doesn't match, that's one thing. But if you are trying to match a valid decimal number, this regex is not adequate. Obviously `\d{2}` is more a format than a validation.

Comment: str
".00.001.00.001.00.00.001.002.00.00.00.00.002.004.00.00.001.00.00.00.005.001.001.0028.00.001.00.005.00.004.004.00.002.006.00.0025.001.002.00.00.002.001.00.002.004.001.006.00.00.00.00" I want to split it into an array [.00, .00, 1.00 ........................]

Comment: var re = /^(\.[0-9]{2})$/
undefined
re.test(".00")
true
re.test("0.00")
false
re.test(".20")
true   I am not sure how do I split it though str.split(re,',')

Answer (score 1):

The trailing zeroes are truncated when the automatic string conversion is done during the call to `test()`. You could use `toFixed()` to do the string conversion manually instead.

For example:

```js
var re = /^([0-9]*)(\.[0-9]{2})$/;

re.test((.22).toFixed(2)); //True
re.test((.20).toFixed(2)); //True
re.test((10.02).toFixed(2)); //True
re.test((10.20).toFixed(2)); //True
re.test((10.00).toFixed(2)); //True
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing numbers to `re.test`, while you should be passing strings, like so:

```
re.test('.22')
re.test('.20')
re.test('10.02')
re.test('10.00')
```